# Electromagnetic tensor in CGS units

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

To write the electromagnetic field tensor in CGS units I just have to kick off the c-s from the SI tensor right?
I know this is a stupid question but I need a reliable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In S.I units the electromagnetic tensor is

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}[F^{\mu \alpha}F^{\nu}_{\alpha}-\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{4}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}]$$

Now, in CGS units, the permitivity and permeability are

$$\epsilon_{0}=\frac{1}{4\pi}$$ and $$\mu_{0}=4\pi$$

Thus, the tensor in cgs units is

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{4\pi}[F^{\mu \alpha}F^{\nu}_{\alpha}-\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{4}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}]$$